# Getting current CF stack value with Serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

Is it possible to read the current value for a particular parameter, (say `functions.function.memorySize`) and then alter it (say I add a few gigs to it) dynamically in [`serverless.yml`](https://www.serverless.com/)?

Comment: I would suggest to understand and fix the weird behaviour instead of hardcoding a workaround that you do not actually understand.

Comment: Fair enough; although, I see there's value in figuring out how to read and manipulate values from an existing CF stack from inside the `serverless.yml` – I'll update the question accordingly.